# Django: migrations for application without models

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application without models. It just has templates and uses other applications.
Now, I am migrating to Django 1.9 and I have to introduce migrations for all my applications.

When I try to follow [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps) with this model-less application I see the following:

`python3 manage.py makemigrations my_app
No changes detected in app 'my_app'`

My main concern, that some models may appear in this application in future.
So, should I keep the application without `migrations` or do I  have to manually create initial migration now?

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
    ]
```

Comment: I am afraid this is going to be opinion-based since, from what I recall, there are no official guidelines for the model-less django projects. I don't personally like the idea of having an empty initial migration. Keep the application without any migrations and, once the models would appear, create your first initial migration.